# Where can I find registration tokens on Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

Is there a way to find where registration token is stored on FCM? I guess that registration token is sent from device automatically at some point.
Are there some logs for FCM where I can check if notifications are sent to devices?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer? This seems to be the official document but they don't say how https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-tokens

Comment: No, I didn't. But I am managing token on the app side and I can save the token on our servers with FCM SDK.